# How to List Azure Network Security Group

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network, azure-security

I have created a Powershell script that provides all the available Azure network security groups in all the subscriptions.
The script is like that:

```
############# List All Azure Network Security Groups #############
$subs = Get-AzSubscription

foreach ($sub in $subs) {
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $sub.Id
    $nsgs = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup

    Foreach ($nsg in $nsgs) {
        $nsgRules = $nsg.SecurityRules

        foreach ($nsgRule in $nsgRules) {
            $nsgRule | Select-Object @{Name='SubscriptionName';Expression={$sub.Name}},
                @{Name='ResourceGroupName';Expression={$nsg.ResourceGroupName}},
                @{Name='NetworkSecurityGroupName';e={$nsg.Name}},
                Name,Description,Priority,
                @{Name='SourceAddressPrefix';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.SourceAddressPrefix))}},
                @{Name='SourcePortRange';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.SourcePortRange))}},
                @{Name='DestinationAddressPrefix';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.DestinationAddressPrefix))}},
                @{Name='DestinationPortRange';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.DestinationPortRange))}},
                Protocol,Access,Direction,
                @{Name='NetworkInterfaceName';Expression={$nsg.NetworkInterfacesText}},
                @{Name='SubnetName';Expression={$nsg.SubnetsText}} |
                    Export-Csv "C:\Users\admin-vishal.singh\Desktop\Test\nsg\NSG-C10.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII -Append        
        }
    }
}
```

It provides output like this:
[image: ouput-CSV]

as you can see in the above output it is returning a blank value for NSG attached to which NICs and Subnets.

I also tried some changes in code like that

```
@{Name='NetworkInterfaceName';Expression={$nsg.NetworkInterfaces}},
@{Name='SubnetName';Expression={$nsg.Subnets}}
```

but also gives a blank column as output.

I am trying to get NICs and subnet to which NSGs are linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above question.
Please find the script for the same.

```
############# List All Azure Network Security Groups #############
$subs = Get-AzSubscription

foreach ($sub in $subs) {
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $sub.Id
    $nsgs = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup

    Foreach ($nsg in $nsgs) {
        $nsgRules = $nsg.SecurityRules

        foreach ($nsgRule in $nsgRules) {
            $nsgRule | Select-Object @{Name='SubscriptionName';Expression={$sub.Name}},
                @{Name='ResourceGroupName';Expression={$nsg.ResourceGroupName}},
                @{Name='NetworkSecurityGroupName';e={$nsg.Name}},
                Name,Description,Priority,
                @{Name='SourceAddressPrefix';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.SourceAddressPrefix))}},
                @{Name='SourcePortRange';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.SourcePortRange))}},
                @{Name='DestinationAddressPrefix';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.DestinationAddressPrefix))}},
                @{Name='DestinationPortRange';Expression={[string]::join(",", ($_.DestinationPortRange))}},
                Protocol,Access,Direction,
                @{Name='NetworkInterfaceName';Expression={$nsg.NetworkInterfaces.Id.Split('/')[-1]}},
                @{Name='SubnetName';Expression={$nsg.Subnets.Id.Split('/')[-1]}} |
                    Export-Csv "C:\Users\admin-vishal.singh\Desktop\Test\nsg\NSG-C100.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII -Append        
        }
    }
}
```